# I can't upload images to my free blog in blogger.com

Tags: blogger

When I try to upload images, of any type, to my blog on [www.blogger.com](http://www.blogger.com), It upload successfully but the image isn't visible, neither in the design view nor in the blog view.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Could be everything or nothing or anything in between.

- Wrong file format
- Technical difficulties at your side
- Technical difficulties at blogger.com
- Some kind of Browser addon blocking the display of these images.

My magic crystal ball recommended to first ask the blogger.com support.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the post and add all content into a new post. Delete all images and upload images from your local computer.